# Dell Optiplex 9010 will not post with PCIe graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, troubleshooting, pci-express, post

I was given a Dell Optiplex 9010 minitower to troubleshoot.  Everything works fine, until you plug in a PCIe graphics card.  The machine boots off the Intel integrated graphics. If a PCIe graphics card is plugged in to either PCIe slot, the computer will not post.  If the graphics card has a fan, it will spin up to max speed and sit there.  The monitor detects no video and goes to sleep.  At that point nothing can be done, other than power off the machine.  I have tried this with four known working PCIe graphics cards that require no additional power from the PSU.  The BIOS is up to date, for what that is worth.  BIOS is also set to auto for graphics.  The only other option is integrated.  I am fairly certain its not the PSU.  Even though its only 240W, the cards all work in a machine with a 236W PSU.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: How much RAM does the machine have, and how much memory is on the card? Does the card work in a different machine? And what card is it?

Comment: @NiKiZe I appreciate you are trying to help, but memory on the machine and the graphics cards are irrelevant.  And I said I tried 4 different cards that  work.

Comment: Memory might not be irrelevant due to the fact how the memory is addressed. Called PCI BAR. Could you maybe force the machine to only use integrated, which would make it use that during post, and then switch over to the other GPU inside OS, even if that is not what you want, it is one step in the debug process.

Comment: Possibly a physical motherboard socket issue. Inserting the card may cause an open or false conductor path.

Comment: @NiKiZe  It will not post with the any PCIe graphics card inserted, regardless of integrated or external being set.

Comment: @John Not likely as none of them work in either of the 2 PCIe slots.

Comment: Not likely as none of them work in either of the 2 PCIe slots   .....   I agree but the PCIe slots will (likely) share common electrical circuit paths. The issue does not appear to be Power Supply, and there is not much else (PS, Main Board, Memory, CPU) to consider.

Answer (score 1):

I put this off for a while, but came back to it recently.  The PCIe slots only support low power (watts) graphics cards.  I found a forum eventually where people were discussing this issue.  Not sure why I didnt find it before, but other people had the same problem.  Unfortunately, the Dell Optiplex 9010's are artificially limited to be "business class" machines.  Dell did not want users putting in a decent GPU into these machines.

[image: Power limits]

For my use of these machines, its fine.  However, the info might be useful for other people.  After rummaging through a box of parts, I found a card that is compatible in the correct slot.  So now I can run it to a TV with HDMI.

Comment: The other slot seems to have full 75W available, so it should work fine as long as the BIOS doesn't cause further problems. It's wired for only 4 lanes though so it can be a bottleneck. One could also try cards that use external power connectors with an additional PSU.